# Factory methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, factory

**What is the slickest, most Ruby-like way to have a single constructor return an object of the appropriate type?**

To be more specific, here's a dummy example: say I have two classes `Bike` and `Car` which subclass `Vehicle`. I want this:

```
Vehicle.new('mountain bike')  # returns Bike.new('mountain bike')
Vehicle.new('ferrari')        # returns Car.new('ferrari')
```

I've proposed a solution below, but it uses `allocate` which seems way too implementation-heavy. What are some other approaches, or is mine actually ok?

Comment: Could you use mixins? What I mean is do you have to have clases for Bike and Car? Could you have a Bike and Car mixin that could be included or extended into the created object in the constructor.

Comment: Hmm, I guess so in principle - though that's more of a hack - the correct OO concept is that the resulting object 'is a' bike or car, not 'behaves like' a bike or car.

Comment: How does your code know what kind of object is required? Is some sort of lookup table involved?

Comment: It looks like you have complex construction requirements. Putting this into the inheritance hierarchy is going to obscure the business logic. Either accept that you need specific sub-classes for 'MountainBike' etc or do as others have suggested and encapsulate the construction logic in a separate factory class(es). That's gnerally the best approach over time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I make a factory method that is not called<sup>1</sup> `new` or `initialize`, I guess that doesn't really answer the question "how do I make a ... constructor ...", but I think that's how I would do it...

```
class Vehicle
  def Vehicle.factory vt
    { :Bike => Bike, :Car => Car }[vt].new
  end
end

class Bike < Vehicle
end

class Car < Vehicle
end
```

---

```
c = Vehicle.factory :Car
c.class.factory :Bike
```

---

<sup>1. Calling the method *factory* works really well in this instructional example but IRL you may want to consider [@AlexChaffee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190135/alexchaffee)'s advice in the comments.</sup>

Comment: That's the approach I'd take, as then you don't have to worry about how `new` works.

Comment: I recommend not calling it "factory". That's confusing the pattern with the implementation. Instead name it something like "create" or "from_style".

Answer (score 17):

I did this today. Translated into vehicles it would look like this:

```
class Vehicle
  VEHICLES = {}

  def self.register_vehicle name
    VEHICLES[name] = self
  end

  def self.vehicle_from_name name
    VEHICLES[name].new
  end
end

class Bike < Vehicle
  register_vehicle 'mountain bike'
end

class Car < Vehicle
  register_vehicle 'ferrari'
end
```

I like that the labels for the classes are kept with the classes themselves, instead of having information about a subclass stored with the superclass. The constructor is not called `new`, but I see no benefit in using that particular name, and it would make things trickier.

```
> Vehicle.vehicle_from_name 'ferrari'
=> #<Car:0x7f5780840448>
> Vehicle.vehicle_from_name 'mountain bike'
=> #<Bike:0x7f5780839198>
```

Note that *something* needs to make sure those subclasses are loaded before vehicle_from_name is run (presumably these three classes would be in different source files), otherwise the superclass will have no way of knowing what subclasses exists, i.e. you cannot depend on autoload to pull those classes in when running the constructor.

I solved this by putting all subclasses in e.g. a `vehicles` subdirectory and adding this to the end of `vehicle.rb`:

```
require 'require_all'
require_rel 'vehicles'
```

Uses the `require_all` gem (found at https://rubygems.org/gems/require_all and https://github.com/jarmo/require_all)

Comment: According to my understanding when I wrote this, this shouldn't have worked. I didn't realize it at the time, but this only works because class variable references are shared with subclasses under certain circumstances.

Comment: Nice answer. But, can anyone please help me understand that why a class level variable instead of a constant?? like: `VARIABLES = {}` instead of `@@vehicles = {}`??

Comment: A constant would work and would even work better because the "certain circumstances" are less confusing. :-)

Good call.

Comment: @Surya, a constant is a constant. `VEHICLES` shouldn't change once it has been initialized.

Comment: @clacke A class variable is totally appropriate in this situation. A changing constant completely violates the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 6):

Adapted from [here](http://ola-bini.blogspot.com/2007/12/code-size-and-dynamic-languages.html), I have

```
class Vehicle
  def self.new(model_name)
    if model_name == 'mountain bike'  # etc.
      object = Bike.allocate
    else
      object = Car.allocate
    end
    object.send :initialize, model_name
    object
  end
end

class Bike < Vehicle
  def initialize(model_name)
  end
end

class Car < Vehicle
  def initialize(model_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't know why you went looking any further than this.  Not sure exactly what you mean by "implementation-heavy", but this looks like The Ruby Way to me.

Answer (score 4):

What about an included Module instead of a superclass? That way, you still get `#kind_of?` to work, and there's no default `new` that gets in the way.

```
module Vehicle
  def self.new(name)
    when 'mountain bike'
      Bike.new(name)
    when 'Ferrari'
      Car.new(name)
    ...
    end
  end
end

class Bike
  include Vehicle
end

class Car
  include Vehicle
end
```

Comment: hmmm, it's clean, and slick - my concern is that it seems more like a hack than a 'pure' solution. a Bike /is a Vehicle/, not a Bike /acts like a Vehicle/. This suggests to me that the right concept is a subclass rather than a mixin.

Comment: It's a fair point, though I think that distinction is more felt in the Java-ey world than the Ruby world. `kind_of?` and `is_a?` both return `true` for modules, which implies to me that the Ruby mindset is that modules *can* be used for "is-a" metaphors.

Answer (score 2):

```
class VehicleFactory
  def new() 
    if (wife_allows?)
       return Motorcycle.new
    else
       return Bicycle.new
    end
  end
end

class vehicleUser 
  def doSomething(factory)
    a_vehicle = factory.new()
  end
end
```

and now we can do...

```
client.doSomething(Factory.new)
client.doSomething(Bicycle)    
client.doSomething(Motorcycle)
```

You can see this example in the book *Design Patterns in Ruby* ([Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452)).

Comment: This is different to what I'm after - I want the factory method to be in the superclass of the derived objects.

Comment: `if(wife_allows?)` brilliant

Answer (score 1):

You can clean things up a bit by changing `Vehicle#new` to:

```
class Vehicle
  def self.new(model_name = nil)
    klass = case model_name
      when 'mountain bike' then Bike
      # and so on
      else                      Car
    end
    klass == self ? super() : klass.new(model_name)
  end
end

class Bike < Vehicle
  def self.new(model_name)
    puts "New Bike: #{model_name}"
    super
  end
end

class Car < Vehicle
  def self.new(model_name)
    puts "New Car: #{model_name || 'unknown'}"
    super
  end
end
```

The last line of `Vehicle.new` with the ternary statement is important. Without the check for `klass == self` we get stuck in an infinite loop and generate the StackError that others were pointing out earlier. Note that we have to call `super` with parentheses. Otherwise we'd end up calling it with arguments which `super` doesn't expect.

And here are the results:

```
> Vehicle.new
New Car: unknown # from puts
# => #<Car:0x0000010106a480>

> Vehicle.new('mountain bike')
New Bike: mountain bike # from puts
# => #<Bike:0x00000101064300>

> Vehicle.new('ferrari')
New Car: ferrari # from puts
# => #<Car:0x00000101060688>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You'll get a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. This illustrates one of the main problems: you can't both override new and call it without some extra work

Comment: The system stack error only happens when Bike and Car are subclasses of Vehicle

Comment: Peter, you're right, I was a bit hasty with that solution. Let me fix it to avoid the StackError.