# How to return new instance of subclass while initializing parent class?

Tags: ruby, oop, class, inheritance

Given a class hierarchy as follows:

```ruby
class A
  def initialize(param)
    if param == 1 then
      #initialize and return instance of B
    else
      #initialize and return instance of C
    end
  end
end

class B < A
end

class C < A
end
```

Is it possible to actually initialize and return an instance of `B` or `C` when initializing `A`? I.e. `my_obj = A.new(param)` would result in `my_obj` being an instance of class `B` or `C` depending on the value of `param`, which gets checked in `A.initialize(param)`.

In my usecase its only known at runtime which subclass (`B` or `C`) to use and the parent class (`A`) is basically never really used.
I thought it might be a good idea to move the logic of deciding whether `B` or `C` into their common ancestor.

If this is not possible (or bad style), where should I put the check of `param` and the decision which class to initialize?

Comment: Similar questions have been answered before. What you are probably looking for are factory methods. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515577/factory-methods-in-ruby I guess the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515580/1128705 will fit your needs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're breaking a fundamental OO principle here -- classes should know nothing about their subclasses. Of course, sometimes principles should be broken, but there's no apparent reason to do it here.

A far better solution is to shift the instantiation logic to a factory method in a separate class. The factory method takes the same arguments as the A's initializer above, and returns an instance of the appropriate class.

Comment: Thanks for saying it out loud. :) I finally wrote a method `initiate_A` in a separate module, which does the decision and returns a new object.

Comment: There might be one or two cases where this is appropriate though. As I said in my answer, what if you have a parser class, that has to deal with, for example, different versions of a language? You could have a constructor that returns an instance of the right subclass for the right version of the data. HTML5 is HTML isen't a good inheritance relationship, I don't know what is.

Comment: We're agreeing with each other -- this principle can be broken when there's good reason to. Not sure I like your example though, it sounds more like a case for Abstract Factory.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is, the return value of `initialize` is ignored. here's what happens when you call `A.new`:

- `new` calls a special class method called `allocate` -- this returns an empty instance of the class
- `new` then calls `initialize` on the object returned by `allocate`, and returns the object

To do what you want to do, you need to override `new` and make it do what you want:

```
class A
  def self.new(args*)
    if(args[0]==1)
      B.new(*args[1..-1])
    else
      C.new(*args[1..-1])
    end
  end
end
```

There is something else to consider though. If `A` is never really used on its own, you should be using some sort of factory method, or, just a simple if statement. Eg:

```
def B_or_C(param,args)
  (param == 1 ? B : C).new(args)
end
```

The design really depends on what you are using them for. When you, for example, have a class that could be used to handle multiple versions of something, for example, HTML, you could have a main class `HTMLParser` which overrode `new` and could return any of its subclasses: `HTML1Parser`, `HTML2Parser`, `HTML3Parser`, `HTML4Parser`, and `HTML5Parser`.

Note: You have to override the `new` method to the default in the sub-classes to prevent infinite looping:

```
def self.new(args*)
  obj=allocate
  obj.send(:initialize, *args)
  obj
end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. However, when overriding `self.new` in `A` and calling `A.new(params)`, I'm getting an error: `SystemStackError: stack level too deep`. It seems, that calling `B.new` (or `C.new`) inside of `A.new` causes an infinite loop as the "constructors" of `B` and `C` are somehow calling the "constructor" of `A`, namely `A.new`.

Comment: @ismaelga: Exactly. When the `new` method for `B` is called, it goes up the inheritance chain to `A`, who instantiates `B` again, which causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding new, you could create a `self.instantiate` method which would then call `.new`.