# Ruby on Rails - Call a method for each subclass from the parent class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, ruby-on-rails-4, inheritance

I'm using Ruby on Rails with the following class structure:

```
class Parent
  def self.parse
    self.subclasses.each(&:parse) # how to fix this?
  end
end

class Child1 < Parent
  def self.parse
    # ...
  end
end

class Child2 < Parent
  def self.parse
    # ...
  end
end
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
Parent.parse
=> Child1.parse and Child2.parse
```

But actually the child classes are not loaded and so the `subclasses` methods give empty array.

Is there a easy way to do this very common task?

Comment: What you're trying to acomplish? Parent class doesn't have access to the Child's. Maybe what you need can be done in another way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074175/how-to-return-new-instance-of-subclass-while-initializing-parent-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because rails autoloads classes: `Parent` doesn't know about its subclasses until they used somewhere or required.

Just require them all manually from the `Parent` class:

```
# parent.rb
require 'child1'
require 'child2'

class Parent
  def self.parse
    self.subclasses.each(&:parse) # how to fix this?
  end
end
```

Comment: Absolutely right that it's the auto loading causing the problem (you can turn this off if you need to in `config/development.rb`) but I'm not sure the right place to require them is the parent class. Wouldn't it be better to do it in application.rb, or an initializer, or in config/development.rb if that's the only environment the problem will occur in.

Comment: @Shadwell, yeah you are right that there is may be a better place. This is just how I feel about the class readability. I'd put this into the `parent` class since it makes clear at first glance that this class doesn't rely on rails autoload feature.