# A function that returns an object

Tags: ruby

I need a function `car()` that returns a `Car` object. A file with the following code works:

```
class Car
  def something
    true
  end
end

def car
  Car.new
end
```

Is it right to place the function in the same file outside of the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically? Yes, that is fine.

But it sounds to me like you are looking for something more ala **Factory Methods**. Here is a good read: [Factory methods in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515577/factory-methods-in-ruby).

It is a good practice if you want to create functions that make new objects with customized parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Factory inside Car class

```
class Car
  def initialize(brand, name)
    @brand = brand
    @name = name
  end

  def something_cool
    puts "My #{@name} from #{@brand} does cool things"
  end

  def self.ferrari
    Car.new("Ferrari", "F-40")
  end 
end
```

Then you can use:

```
ferrari = Car.ferrari
ferrari.something_cool
```

Some reference: [Creational patterns](https://practicingruby.com/articles/creational-design-patterns)